# Invalid library php_pdo_oci8.dll and pdo not loaded

Tags: windows-xp, apache-http-server, php, wamp

Starting wampmysqld works fine, but trying to **start** the **wampapache** service **doesn't work** (even if I start it from services.msc or from the WAMP icon > Apache > Start/Resumt Service).

During the starting, it shows:

[image: Service Control]

When it loaded:

- about one half, it shows:

  [image: Apache HTTP Server]

  If I click on "Don't Send":

  [image: Services]
- 100%, it shows:

  [image: Services]

The content of **php_error.log** (from `wamp\logs`):

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'php_pdo_oci8.dll'  in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'pdo_sqlite' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'PDO_OCI' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'PDO_ODBC' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'pdo_pgsql' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Cannot load module 'SQLite' because required module 'pdo' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

The `extension_dir` from **php.ini** contains the **absolute path** (also tried to change the slashes to `\` and to `\\`, but it doesn't work):

```
extension_dir = "f:/wamp/php/ext/"
```

In the f:/wamp/php/ext/ directory, I can find both:

- php_pdo_oci8.dll
- php_pdo.dll

I also tried to add the following lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll
extension=php_pdo.dll
```

in php.ini, but nothing has been solved.

It was running fine before restarting the machine, but for some applications (not for all of them) it threw:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in ... on line ...

How can I solve this problem?

**Details:**

- WAMP5 Version 1.6.6

  - APACHE 2.0.59
  - PHP 5.2.0 and PECL
  - MYSQL 5.0.27
  - PHPMYADMIN 2.9.0.3
  - SQLITEMANAGER 1.2.0
- Windows XP
- port 80 is not used when I try to start it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **fixed** it doing the following steps:

1. Made some Windows updates.
2. Removed my system variable `WAMP_PHP=F:\wamp\php`.
3. Removed `;%WAMP_PHP%;%WAMP_PHP%\bin` from the `PATH`.
4. Restarted computer
5. Run **launch_wampserver.bat** from `F:\wamp`

I don't know which one of the steps fixed the problem, but after all these steps the problem is fixed.